# Aim at words separated by a vertical line Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, readline, txt

I have a text file in which this line is present.

```
 NAME                     = DE: NAME_DE |EN: NAME EN (EXAMPLE) |IT: NAME, IT
```

I would like to target the names in the three languages by forming a list.
This is my approach, but unfortunately I cannot find a way to target just the three words:

```
materialfile_obj = open (material_dict["Old_plaster"], 'r',encoding = 'latin-1')
materialfile = materialfile_obj.readlines()
flag_name = 0
for i in range(len(materialfile)):
    if  "NAME" in materialfile[i] and "="  in materialfile[i]:
        line_name = i
        flag_name = 1
if flag_name == 1:
    names = materialfile[line_name].split(" = ")[1].split()
if names:
    for name in names:
        try:
             Name_groups[name].append(All)
        except Exception:
             Name_groups[name] = [All]
else:
    try:
         Name_groups["No_value"].append(All)
    except Exception:
         Name_groups["No_value"] = [All]
materialfile_obj.close()
```

in this way I get a list for each word present but I cannot target only the names.

Comment: What is your desired output based on your example?

Comment: A list of words in the three languages:
list = ["NAME_DE", "NAME EN (EXAMPLE)", "NAME, IT"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regular expressions you can do it on one line by searching for substrings between `:` and `|`.

```
import re

s = 'NAME                     = DE: NAME_DE |EN: NAME EN (EXAMPLE) |IT: NAME, IT'
s += '|' # add pipe to find strings between : and |
names = re.findall(':(.*?)[|]', s)
print(names)
```